# what is good practice using UIAlertView with UIActivityIndicator

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uialertview

I've read a lot here about misusage of UIAlertView and the fact that Apple may reject an app where UIAlertView is overused.

In my app I'm writing I have to update data rarely via online request and recalculating internal data structures. While this is in effect and running in a second thread I don't want that the user touches the GUI and the app's current settings etc. So I decided to show an UIAlertView with UIActivityIndicator and a UIProgessView for some seconds which is dismissed automatically when background work is done.

Do you think that it is a reason against HIG rules? If so do you have suggestions for good practice on this kind of work flow?

Cheers,
Konran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a UIAlertView, I'd use MBProgressHUD.  It looks nicer and has a built in activity indicator.  Apple uses a similar component in some of their apps.

https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Thanks all! This solution looks really good and I'll try it for sure :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an alertView should be used to stop a user from interacting with the screen. What you can easily do is add a "mask" on top of your content. Create a view; give a background color of .5 alpha black, and add it as a subview of your main view. This will dim everything else, and stop the user from interacting with it.

Comment: If you're going to prevent user interaction, I think using an alert view would be much better than just adding a darkened view on top of your GUI. The alert view will do the darkening of the background with the added benefit of letting the user know what's going on, instead of just leaving him in the dark.

Comment: But an alertView is designed to be dismissed by the user after the user reads what it has to say. Preventing a user from dismissing an alertView doesn't sound good. With the darkened screen; you can add any progress bar or other text that tells the user what is happening and to please wait. Though it looks like TomSwift's solution works better anyway.

Comment: Ok, but if you mention the statement of hennes when an alertView doesn't have any buttons to dismiss (as my app is like) the user won't take it as a usual alert...

Answer (score 0):

I have used an alert view with integrated activity indicator in a couple of apps and none of them was rejected from entering the AppStore. If you don't display any button inside the alert view the user won't even consider it as an alert view, so I don't see any problem with that.